# How to create a coverage store using the geoserver-restconfig python package?

Tags: python, geoserver

My os is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and my python versions is 3.10.6. I am trying to create a coverage store in geoserver using the geoserver-restconfig python package. Here is my code:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
cat = Catalog(service_url='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest',
              username='FAKE_USERNAME',
              password='FAKE_PASSWORD')

# Create working space
cat.create_workspace(name='demo', uri='http://demo')

# Create coverage store
path = 'indicators/coolingdd/rcp_2_6/ensemble/coolingdd_rcp26_multi-model-mean_-_-_20210101-20301230.tiff'
cat.create_coveragestore(name='NAME',
                         workspace='demo',
                         path=path,
                         type='GeoTIFF',
                         create_layer=True,
                         layer_name='TITLE',
                         upload_data=False)
```

The indicators directory is inside the directory where I am running my python script from. Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iliamous/PycharmProjects/winbank-esg-risk-gis-platform/scratch_work.py", line 767, in <module>
    cat.create_coveragestore(name='NAME',
  File "/home/iliamous/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geoserver/catalog.py", line 617, in create_coveragestore
    raise FailedRequestError('Failed to create coverage/layer {} for : {}, {}'.format(layer_name, name,
geoserver.catalog.FailedRequestError: Failed to create coverage/layer TITLE for : NAME, 500
```

Why is this happening?

---

### ----------------------------Update---------------------------------

I have changed the logging level to developer from the global settings but I still receive the same error. This is what my global settings look like:
[image]

---

### --------------------------------Update-------------------------------

Here is the relevant part of the log files:

```
06 Mar 11:25:48 WARN   [gce.geotiff] - File /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/indicators/coolingdd/rcp_2_6/ensemble/coolingdd_rcp26_multi-model-mean_-_-_20210101-20301230.tiff does not exist.
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: File /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/indicators/coolingdd/rcp_2_6/ensemble/coolingdd_rcp26_multi-model-mean_-_-_20210101-20301230.tiff does not exist.
```

My understanding was that the create_coveragestore function also uploaded the tiff file to the geoserver. Apparently, I have to upload the files inside the data directory and then use the function with the correct path from the data directory of geoserver to create the coverage store.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I have changed the logging level to developer but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: what is in the **geoserver** log file?

Comment: it has a lot of lines. anything in particular that I should look for?

Comment: watch what appears when you run the command - you're looking for WARN or ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uploading the indicators directory to /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data directory everything works fine. Apparently, create_coveragestory root directory for the path parameter is the data directory.